# Different margin top from the second page with first page odoo report

Tags: xml, odoo, report, qweb, qwebpage

Hey everyone i create a custom external layout that is empty of logo or information of company, i used for my report with a paper format A4 with 40mm margin top and 30 mm margin botoom but when i printed, the first page has extra space header that the others pages not how can i solvet?
[report result img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwfQN.png)

this is the code of the custom external layout

```
<templateid="custom_external_layout_empty"><tt-if="not o"t-set="o"t-value="doc"/><tt-if="not company"><tt-if="company_id"><tt-set="company"t-value="company_id"/></t><tt-elif="o and 'company_id' in o and o.company_id.sudo()"><tt-set="company"t-value="o.company_id.sudo()"/></t><tt-else="else"><tt-set="company"t-value="res_company"/></t></t><divclass="header"><divclass="row"><divclass="col-12"><br/><br/><br/></div></div></div><divclass="footer"><divclass="row">
</div></div><tt-if="company.external_report_layout_id"t-call="{{company.external_report_layout_id.sudo().key}}"><tt-out="0"/></t><tt-else="else"t-call="web.external_layout_standard"><tt-out="0"/></t>
```

this is the code of the report

```
<templateid="report_eco_obs_gen"><tt-call="web.html_container"><tt-foreach="docs"t-as="doc"><tt-call="auto_appointment.custom_external_layout_empty"><divclass="page"style="font-family:Calibri;"><divclass="oe_structure"/><palign="center"style="font-size: 14pt"><strong><u>ECOGRAFÍA 11 - 14 SEMANAS DE GESTACIÓN</u></strong></p><divclass="row mt16 mb8"style="font-size: 12pt"><divclass="col-12"><spanstyle="margin-right: 91px;">Fecha y Hora</span>: <spant-field="doc.date_atention"t-options="{'widget': 'datetime', 'format': 'dd/MM/yyyy, HH:MM:SS'}"/><br/><spanstyle="margin-right: 125px;">Nombre</span>:<tt-if="not doc.hc_obstetric_id"><spant-field="doc.patient_id_gin"/></t><tt-else="else"><spant-field="doc.patient_id"/></t><br/><spanstyle="margin-right: 144px;">Edad</span>:<tt-if="not doc.hc_obstetric_id"><spant-field="doc.patient_id_gin.age"/></t><tt-else="else"><spant-field="doc.patient_id.age"/></t><br/><spanstyle="margin-right: 110px;">Indicación</span>: <spant-field="doc.indication"/><br/><spanstyle="margin-right: 36px;">Condiciones Técnicas</span>: <spant-field="doc.tecnical_condition"/><br/><spanstyle="margin-right: 112px;">Embarazo</span>: <spant-field="doc.pregnant"/><br/><spanstyle="margin-right: 146px;">FUR</span>:<tt-if="not doc.hc_obstetric_id"><spant-field="doc.date_fur_gin"t-options="{'widget': 'date', 'format': 'dd/MM/yyyy'}"/></t><tt-else="else"><spant-field="doc.date_fur"t-options="{'widget': 'date', 'format': 'dd/MM/yyyy'}"/></t><br/><spanstyle="margin-right: 5px;">Edad Gestacional por FUR</span>: <spant-field="doc.gestational_age"/><br/><spanstyle="margin-right: 21px;">Fecha Probable de Parto</span>: <spant-field="doc.date_birth"/><br/><palign="center"><strong><u>EVALUACIÓN ECOGRÁFICA FETAL</u></strong></p><em><spant-field="doc.description"/></em></div></div><br/><br/><divclass="text-center"><imgt-att-src="'/auto_appointment/static/img/sello.png'"height="100"border="1"width="170"/></div></div></t></t></t></template>
```

how can i solve the space header to get the same space in every pages